# Save csv file directly to S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some python code that saves a response from an api to the file system of my computer.  How can save the api response (csv) directly to an amazon s3 bucket without having to save it to my computers file system.

I've looked at examples using bot03 but they only show examples of uploading from a local file system.  What I want to do is save the csv file **directly** to the s3 bucket.  Any advice would be appreciated - im a python newbie.

This is the code im using to save to the local file system:

```
import requests
import csv

def main():
    url = "https://api0.solar.sheffield.ac.uk/pvlive/v3/pes/10?start=2021-01-01T00:00:00&end=2021-07-06T00:00:00&data_format=csv"
    x = requests.get(url,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',})
#save to csv
    with open('C:\\Users\myDirectory\myFile.csv', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(x.content)
```

Many thanks

Comment: ok, so far I have this:

    s3 = bot03.client("s3")
    with open("test.csv","rb") as file2:
        s3.upload_fileobj(x.conent, "BUCKETNAME", "FILENAMEFORS3.CSV")

how do I pass credentials to connect to my bucket?

Comment: You can store your credentials on your computer by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command. It will store them in `~/.aws/credentials`, which will be automatically detected by boto3.

Answer (score 0):

boto3's `put_object` supports uploading file from `bytes` or `file`, which doesn't require you to save it to file first:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object

> Body=b'bytes'|file,